# C# syntax to get access to webcontrol in different file (aspx)

Tags: c#

Within my Website project, I have some aspx pages, javascript files, and a custom C# class I called MyCustomReport.  I placed a Image box with an ID of Image1 inside SelectionReport.aspx.  I need to get access to that Image1 inside MyCustomReport.cs so I can turn it on and off based on conditions.  What code do I need to do this?  Thanks everyone

Comment: Just for the record, that sounds like a really weird design.

Comment: This doesn't sound quite right, why would your report be changing your webpage ? surley you cant be rendering your report and webpage at the same time..

Comment: Your page should be responsible for turning things on and off on itself and your report class should just return data (preferably enough to tell the page what to do).  This reduces coupling between the two classes.

Comment: BTW...if this is related to your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733139/display-an-image-using-c-in-web-application) you are going in the wrong direction.

Comment: Just for the record, my vote is with ROMANARMY on this one. You're mixing display logic with business logic, in a horrid spaghetti code mess. Think of each class or page as an autonomous unit. Sure you'll have to interface between classes (that's rather the point, yeah?) but you're only going to interface between them. You don't steer your car by engaging the blinker system, and you don't have to open the oil cap to unlock the trunk. Keep separate systems separate. Turn the image on and off on the page, where it's conceptually located.

Comment: I agree, my bad.. I simply want to display a loading icon when the report is being generated and I want the visibility of the icon to be false when the report is completed.

Comment: Take a look at danswain's answer to your other question.  Your page will be sent to the client and finish rendering before the report has been generated.  At that point it will be too late to change the image from inside your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to pass the instance of `Image` control to `MyCustomReport`.  From there you'll be able to set it's `Visible` property to `true` or `false`.

Probably something like this

```
public partial class SelectionReport : Page
{
    // your code here

    protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e ){
        MyCustomReport myCustomReport = new MyCustomReport();
        myCustomReport.MyReport( Image1 );
    }
}

public class MyCustomReport
{
    public void MyReport( Image arg ){
        // some more code
        arg.Visible = false; // or true
    }
}
```

**EDIT** derek is right, you won't need the entire page, just the image.

Comment: Hi Romanarmy-  Does the code you posted above need to go into something like SelectionReport.aspx.cs? I don't have a cs class for that yet but can create one.

Comment: @Josh: The first class yes, the second class no.  I just put the two together to illustrate a point.  And how do you not have a class for that, doesn't visual studio generate one for you when you add a new page to the project?

Comment: Trying to implement your code but having a little issue (I'm learning, sorry).  I created a file called SelectionReport.aspx.cs and added a reference to the appropriate assembly and then declared it at the top of my class.  Next I added your page_load and in the first line the namespace in MyCustomReport is CustomReports so I declared CustomReports.MyCustomReport RP = new CustomReports.MyCustomReport();  In the second line I tried RP. but intellisense din't show MyCustomReport or am I looking for the wrong thing here.  What did I miss?

Comment: @Josh: You should read this, it goes into more detail about how code behind files work and whatnot. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/015103yb.aspx

Answer (score 0):

it sounds a bit odd to do it that way.  You could pass the control to the class method using the ref keyword, then the class could modify it:

```
doSomething(data, MyUserControl);
```

I think a better implementation would be for your class to have a method or property that the page could query to turn the control on or off.

Comment: @derek: Why would you need to pass it by reference?  He just needs to change the property on the object, not change the object itself.

Comment: To clear things up, MyUserControl would be the Image1 control, not the entire page.  That will give him access to the object to change its property.  Not much different than passing the SelectionReport instance, just narrowing down the reference that is sent.

Comment: agreed. Essentially your suggestion basically implements my second point of just making it a property or method that the page could query.  I would even simplify it further by having: Image1.Visible = MyCustomReport.MyReport(), and have that return a bool.

Comment: correct, I think I had my keywords mixed up, out would definitely be the better solution in my example.